# How can I set the sound profile to silent for a given contact?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire

As the title says, how can I set the sound profile to silent for a given contact? Or in other words, how can I set that a given contact will have no ringtone assigned to it?

I looked at it and apparently I do have the option to set a custom ringtone for a given contact, but I have to pick one ringtone. I cannot pick "none" as an option. So I was thinking maybe there is an app that can accomplish what I want or there might be a trick I can pull off to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having no ringtone assigned to it, get a short silent ringtone (such as the ones found [here](http://jetcityorange.com/silent-ringtone/) and use that to set a silent ring.

Comment: Where do I store the downloaded audio file on the phone?

Comment: It looks like `/system/media/audio/ringtones` is the default directory for the HTC ringtones. But since I can't mount this partition to my PC I will just store it on root of my SD card.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it should scan the music/media folder on your SD card.

Comment: Thanks! I transferred the file to `/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones` where I created the directory "ringtones" manually. So I created that folder first and then transferred not just one but all four files (1 second silence mp3, wav, 10 second silence mp3, wav). The phone didn't scan this location automatically. I had to browse to the file I want to use (with ES File Explorer). But once I picked a file the new location seems to be auto-scanned now because I can see all four files now in the Ringtone settings, even the ones I never used before.

Comment: Unfortunately this method only works when the calling parts phone number is displayed. That's a condition that needs to be fulfilled for this to work. If it's a hidden number it will still ring. Perhaps I can set the same ringtone for the "UNKNOWN" caller? Except, this is not a contact stored in my phone...

Comment: Mr. Number can filter unknown and private calls. You can check it out [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mrnumber.blocker)

Comment: Thanks! But when it comes at 4.8 MB and when I only have 3.20 MB of free internal memory that app can only be a wet dream for me. But I will note down the name of the app for future reference. I might try it out when I upgrade to a smarter "smartphone" that has more than minimum memory.

Comment: That's fine. I thought that you might like the recommendation while since you brought up the issue.